# Elastic Search Query or Watcher

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

since im new to Kibana/Elastic i need help on kibana search query/watcher with below parameters.

```
((condition11 and condition 12 and condition 13) and (condition21 and condition22))
```

i.e.,`((AppName and errorMesg1 and log_level) and (app2 and logMessage))`

```
((App1 AND 'Not_Found 404' AND 'ERROR') AND (App2 AND 'RetryCount is 6.Publsihing message to DLQ'))
```

I tried below, but it is not giving me any result. Let me know where am I missing the query

```
bool:{
should:[
{match_phrase: {appName: "abc"}},
{match_phrase: {log_level: "ERROR"}},
{match_phrase: {ErrorMessage: "Not_Found 404"}},
]},
bool:{
should:[
{match_phrase: {appName: "xyz"}},
{match_phrase: {LogMessage: "RetryCount is 6.Publsihing message to DLQ"}},
]}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need combine conditional use "should" and inside "must". At least one of the clauses in the "musts" must be true.

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "appName": "abc"
                }
              },
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "log_level": "ERROR"
                }
              },
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "ErrorMessage": "Not_Found 404"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "must": [
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "appName": "xyz"
                }
              },
              {
                "match_phrase": {
                  "LogMessage": "RetryCount is 6.Publsihing message to DLQ"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It is not working, if i use "should" - I'm getting results matching "condition21 AND condition22". If i use "must" - I'm getting results matching "condition11 AND condition12"=> But i need combine results of both